# How to load a component inside a nested folder using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

[image: React App Project structure]

The above is the folder structure of my react app 'MyProject'.

Using the above folder structure I am able to use the `Layout` component in `Main.jsx` ( `src/Main.jsx`) by :

`import Layout from './layout'`
(the `layout` folder has `index.js` that by default exports Layout component )

Also I am able to use Content component in `ErrorBoundary.js` ( `src.js/ErrorBoundary.js`) by:

`import Content from '../../layout/content/Content'`
(the `content` folder has `index.js` inside it that exports by default Content component)

But When I try to run webpack I get the following errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './layout/content/Content' in '/home/user/myProject/src'

resolve './layout/content/Content' in '/home/user/myProject/src'

  using description file: /home/user/myProject/package.json (relative path: ./src)

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

    using description file: /home/user/myPoject/package.json (relative path: ./src/layout/content/Content)

  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      //home/user/myProject//src/layout/content/Content doesn't exist
      .js
        
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  
/home/user/myProject//src/layout/content/Content.js doesn't exist
      jsx
        
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
       /home/user/myProject/src/layout/content/Contentjsx doesn't exist
      .css
        
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/myProject//src/layout/content/Content.css doesn't exist
      as directory


        /home/user/myProject//src/layout/content/Content doesn't exist
```

I tried alias to resolve by following the webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) but no luck :

```
alias: {
      Layout: path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/layout/Layout"),
      Content: path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/layout/content/Content")
    }
```

My webpack config is :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
console.log('attaining independence', __dirname)
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', 'jsx', '.css',],
    mainFiles: ['index']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        use: 'url-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|eot|ttf|otf|woff2)$/i,
        use: 'url-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'React App',
    }),
  ],
};
```

am I using alias in right way or is there any other way to handle this error ?.

And there is table just under the [resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) on how to use alias but I couldn't figure out how to use that table in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed folders : `layout` and `content` to `layoutContainer` and `contentContainer` respectively and that worked. There seems to be a problem ( dont know if its a bug in webpack ) when there is a match in import name and file name. Hope it saves someone from hours of debugging and research .

If anyone has valid explaination please do post.Thanks.